# Unwilling server: Can't unlock AD account in code

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, directoryservices

When I try to unlock an AD account using my own C# program, I get the following error:

> System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException (0x80072035): The server is unwilling to process the request.

This is the code I use to unlock the account:

```
// "ldap" is an instance of my own class for accessing an LDAP server

using (DirectoryEntry entry = ldap.GetEntry(objectGuid))
{
    entry.InvokeSet("lockouttime", 0);

    // I also tried:
    entry.Properties["lockouttime"].Clear();

    entry.CommitChanges();
}
```

I use this software in multiple domains and only get this error in one of them and I can't figure out what the difference is. When I use `dsa.msc` to unlock the account, everything works fine.

The error also happens with different user objects, but both versions (`Clear` and `InvokeSet`) work in other environments. Can anyone give me a hint?

P.S.: I use domain admin credentials to access the LDAP server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this problem using the classes in `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`:

```
using (var ctx = new PrincipalContext(
    ContextType.Domain,
    host,
    rootDn,
    ContextOptions.ServerBind | ContextOptions.Negotiate | ContextOptions.SecureSocketLayer,
    username,
    password))
using (var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.Guid, objectGuid.ToString()))
{
    if (user != null)
    {
        user.UnlockAccount();
    }
    else
    {
        // user not found
    }
}
```

But I still don't know what the `UnlockAccount` method does more than setting `lockOutTime` to zero (or clear it).

Answer (score 0):

Try [this example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C#45):

```
   public void Unlock(string userDn)
    {
        try
        {
            DirectoryEntry uEntry = new DirectoryEntry(userDn);
            uEntry.Properties["LockOutTime"].Value = 0; //unlock account

            uEntry.CommitChanges(); //may not be needed but adding it anyways

            uEntry.Close();
        }
        catch (System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException E)
        {
            //DoSomethingWith --> E.Message.ToString();

        }
}
```

Comment: This is pretty much my code (because `InvokeSet` does nothing else than setting `uEntry.Properties["LockOutTime"].Value = 0`) and therefore this code doesn't work - at least in the mentioned environment.